# Why file input inside a button doesn't work in Firefox but works in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple HTML document with the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="/upload_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "fileForm">
    <button id="chooseFileButton">
        Choose File
        <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
    </button>
    <button id="uploadFileButton" type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>

<style>
#fileInput {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

So here file input is hidden and is inside of the button.
Now in Google Chrome when I click the button it opens file dialog as I want. But in Firefox it tries to navigate to the URL in form's action attribute. How I can make Firefox to behave with my HTML like Chrome does? What is the reason of Firefox behaving like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because what you are trying to do is not actually valid HTML. Why not make the fileinput look like a button with a div?

You are not allowed to have a fileinput inside a Button Tag

Like this:

```css
.buttonExample {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonExample">Upload button
    <input type="file" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0;"></input></div>
```

Comment: Just a note that the input is one of the few "void elements".  Meaning, you do not need to close the input tag "</input>" like you do with the div tag or other various elements.